# "Expected Object, got Promise." error when promise passed as a prop

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I just try to pass a Promise as a Prop to a child component which expect a Promise but I have an error that tells the expected type is Object.

I use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) and [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) for my project.

My code looks like this:

```vue
<template>
  <child-component :listPromise="listAsPromise"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop, Inject } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import  { EditableReferentielModel } from '@/api/model/referentiel'
import ReferentielResource from '@/api/resources/referentiel'
import { AxiosResponseExt } from '@/api/resources/index'

export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  @Inject()
  referentielResource: ReferentielResource

  listAsPromise: Promise<EditableReferentielModel[] & AxiosResponseExt> = this.referentielResource.getStadeDeveloppement()
}

</script>
```

```vue
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop, Inject } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import ReferentielResource from '@/api/resources/referentiel'
import { EditableReferentielModel } from '@/api/model/referentiel'
import { AxiosResponseExt } from '@/api/resources/index'

@Component
export default class ChildComponent extends Vue {
  @Inject()
  referentielResource: ReferentielResource

  @Prop({ default: null })
  value: EditableReferentielModel | null
  @Prop({ default: null })
  listPromise: Promise<EditableReferentielModel[] & AxiosResponseExt>

  referentiel: EditableReferentielModel[] = []
  selected: EditableReferentielModel | null = this.value

  async mounted () {
    this.referentiel = await this.listPromise
  }
}
</script>
```

With this code, I still have this error: `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "listPromise". Expected Object, got Promise.` even if the `listPromise` type is set to `any`.

What is wrong ?

Comment: are you setting its default to `null`? (I don't know typescript..) if so, try removing it. as `null` is considered an object

Comment: I do set the default to `null`. But the error persist even if I remove the default value or if a set the expected type to `Promise<T> | null`